# what does this 'that' mean in this sentence?

Tags: optional-that

I'd like to ask a question about the 'that' in the following sentence.

> There are various phony research institutes dedicated to convincing people that global warming is a myth, which were set up by major companies likely to be adversely affected by policies to prevent global warming. Despite losing the media battle, they and their corporate sponsors managed to delay action for a lost decade **that** the next generation should never forgive them for.

Does  this 'that' equal to  'so that'?

Comment: I would say it should be a non-defining relative clause with "which" instead of that, set off with a comma: "... they and their corporate sponsors managed to delay action for a lost decade, which the next generation should never forgive them for".

Answer (score 3):

> ...a lost decade **that** the next generation should never forgive them for.

The "that" refers to "a lost decade." The clause could be rewritten:

> ...a lost decade **for which** the next generation should never forgive them.

Answer (score 1):

> Despite losing the media battle, they and their corporate sponsors managed to delay action for a lost decade **that** the next generation should never forgive them for.

The clause *that the next generation should never forgive them for* is a relative clause and the antecedent of **that** is the NP *a lost decade.*

I would've  preferred a *which* there, instead. The part *which the next generation should never...* would then be set off with commas because it would constitute a nonrestrictive clause.

Furthermore, you could pied-pipe the preposition *for* to the start of the clause: *for which the next generation...*

Comment: Thanks for your explanation! I got it!

Comment: Defining relatives have nouns or nominals as antedecent, but not clauses, so "that" cannot have the clause "to delay action for a lost decade" as its antecedent. Consider that it should be a non-defining relative with "which"

Comment: @BillJ: Thanks a lot once again! :) I hope I have set it right now.